# How to mount a directory such that it has same UID/GID in host as well as container?

Tags: podman

I've been scratching my head and have re-read the man-page for `uidmap`, `gidmap`, `/etc/subuid`, and `/etc/subgid` multiple times when using podman.

I need to mount a source-code directory into a container such that (a) processes within the container have read/write access to the files, as well as (b) processes on the host.

I'm mounting the directory using `-v hostDir:containerDir:U` and files that are initially owned by userID 1000 end-up as owned by userID 1000999 after the container exits.

How do I set this up properly? The files should be available on the host as well as the container with UID/GID=1000/1000

Comment: I would first try  `--userns=keep-id`. If that does not work I would try  `--userns=keep-id --user=$(id -u):$(id -g)`. If that does not work I would try  __--uidmap__ and __--gidmap__ like in my Podman discussion [post](https://github.com/containers/podman/discussions/12970#discussioncomment-2019140)

Comment: I would also first try without the volume option `U`. It will be easier to understand what is going on without that option.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Erik, using `--userns=keep-id` shall solve your issues, though we don't recommend to use with `--user` (not allowed now I guess)

```
podman run -it --userns=keep-id -v <host folder>:<folder inside> alpine
```

Comment: Why is `--user` not recommended to be used with `--userns=keep-id`? Using both worked for me, whereas using just `--userns=keep-id` did not work, and I always got a `touch: test.file: Permission denied` message.